# How to transform an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following task:

Your task is to implement the function `transform(arr)` that takes an array and returns transformed array, based on the control sequences that `arr` contains. Control sequences are defined string elements of the mentioned array:

- `--discard-next` excludes the next element of the array from the transformed array.
- `--discard-prev` excludes the previous element of the array from the transformed array.
- `--double-next` doubles the next element of the array in the transformed array.
- `--double-prev` doubles the previous element of the array in the transformed array.

For example:

```
transform([1, 2, 3, '--double-next', 4, 5]) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

transform([1, 2, 3, '--discard-prev', 4, 5]) => [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

The function must not affect initial array. Control sequences are applied from left to right. Control sequences do not fall into the transformed array. Control sequences in initial array don't occur in a row. If there is no element next to the control sequence to which it can be applied, it does nothing. The function should throw an `Error` if the `arr` is not an `Array`.

I've written the following code:

```js
let transform = function (arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === '--discard-next') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i) + "," + arr.slice(i + 2);
            let newArray = result.split(',');
            return newArray;
        } else if (arr[i] === '--discard-prev') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i - 1) + "," + arr.slice(i + 1);
            let newArray = result.split(',');
            return newArray;
        } else if (arr[i] === '--double-next') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i) + "," + arr[i + 1] + "," + arr.slice(i + 1);
            let newArray = result.split(',');
            return newArray;
        } else if (arr[i] === '--double-prev') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i) + "," + arr[i - 1] + "," + arr.slice(i + 1);
            let newArray = result.split(',');
            return newArray;
        }
    }
};


console.log(transform([1, 2, 3, '--double-next', 4, 5])); // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

console.log(transform([1, 2, 3, '--discard-prev', 4, 5])); // => [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: "*What's wrong with it?*" it seems to work with the samples in the problem statement. Can you give us examples where it doesn't work?

Comment: why do you convert the parts to string and split it again?

Comment: It seems to work, but when I run tests, it 
- doesn't work with an empty array correctly
- affect simple arrays
- basic sequence interactions don't work properly
- advanced sequence interactions don't work properly
- control sequences don't work properly

Answer (score 2):

You could flatMap the values and have a look ahead or behind of the wanted transformation.

```js
let transform = array => array.flatMap((v, i, a) => {
    if (a[i + 1] === '--discard-prev') return [];
    if (a[i - 1] === '--double-next') return [v, v];
    if (a[i + 1] === '--double-prev') return [v, v];
    
    if (v.toString().startsWith('--d')) return [];

    return v;
});
        
console.log(...transform([1, 2, 3, '--double-next', 4, 5]));  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
console.log(...transform([1, 2, 3, '--discard-prev', 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 4, 5]
console.log(...transform([1, 2, 3, '--double-prev', 4, 5])); // [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.join(',');`  that will remove the new line or remove `.split(',')` .

```js
let transform = function (arr) {

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === '--discard-next') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i) + "," + arr.slice(i + 2);
            let newArray = result;
            return newArray;
        } else if (arr[i] === '--discard-prev') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i - 1) + "," + arr.slice(i + 1);
            let newArray = result;
            return newArray;
        } else if (arr[i] === '--double-next') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i) + "," + arr[i + 1] + "," + arr.slice(i + 1);
            let newArray = result;
            return newArray;
        } else if (arr[i] === '--double-prev') {
            let result = arr.slice(0, i) + "," + arr[i - 1] + "," + arr.slice(i + 1);
            let newArray = result;
        
            return newArray;
        }
    }
};

console.log('[',transform([1, 2, 3, '--double-next', 4, 5]),']'); // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

console.log('[',transform([1, 2, 3, '--discard-prev', 4, 5]),']'); // => [1, 2, 4, 5]
```